# The query time of a view increases after having fetched the last page from a view in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: performance, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm using Oracle PL/SQL Developer on a Oracle Database 11g. I have recently written a view with some weird behaviour. When I run the simple query below **without fetching the last page of the query** the query time is about 0.5 sec (0.2 when cached).

```
select * from covenant.v_status_covenant_tuning where bankkode = '4210';
```

However, if i fetch the last page in PL/SQL Developer or if I run the query from Java-code (i.e. I run a query that retrieves all the rows) something happens to the view and the query time increases to about 20-30 secs.

The view does not start working properly again before I recompile it. The explain plan is exactly the same before and after. All indexes and tables are analyzed. I don't know if it's relevant but the view uses a few analytic expressions like rank() over (partition by .....), lag(), lead() and so on.

As I'm new here I can't post a picture of the explain plan (need a reputation of 10) but in general the optimizer uses indexes efficiently and it does a few sorts because of the analytic functions.

Comment: You could check out the *stored* plans in v$sqlstats (and others). Maybe Oracle created a new child-cursor with a different execution plan. Btw: the execution plan is better posted as (formatted) text, not as a picture.

Answer (score 1):

If the plan involves a full scan of some sort, the query will not complete until the very last block in the table has been read.

Imagine a table that has lots of matching rows in the very first few blocks in the table, and no matching rows in the rest of it. If there is a large volume of blocks to check, the query might return the first few pages of results very quickly, as it finds them all in the first few blocks of the table. But before it can return the final "no more results" to the client, it must check every last block of the table - it doesn't know if there might be one more result in the very last block of the table, so it has to wait until it has read that last block.

If you'd like more help, please post your query plan.

Comment: Just to clearify, to problem is not that it takes longer to load all the rows from the view than just the first page, but rather that when you do - the whole view changes somehow. The first time you fetch all the rows the view will take about 4 sec the second time it will take about 25 sec. So in one way or another the view, the optimizer or something else changes and makes the performance much much worse.

Comment: I think you need to get a trace on the sessions (one for the first execution that takes 4s and another for the one that gets 25s) and see what queries exactly are being executed, and what plans are being used. As @a_horse has said, it might be adaptive cursor sharing causing the optimiser to choose a different plan. That's assuming both sessions are actually requesting the entire data set.